# Operator overloading c++ placement

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Im having trouble figuring out where to place the overloaded operators i created. should they be in the class they operate on, or inside? both ways are causing me trouble. any pointers would be great.

here is my very basic uint128_t class:

```
class uint128_t{
    private:
        uint64_t UPPER, LOWER;

    public:
    // constructors
        uint128_t(){
            UPPER = 0;
            LOWER = 0;
        }

        template <typename T>
        uint128_t(T val){
            UPPER = 0;
            LOWER = (uint64_t) val;
        }

        template <typename S, typename T>
        uint128_t(const S & upper_val, const T & lower_val){
            UPPER = (uint64_t) upper_val;
            LOWER = (uint64_t) lower_val;
        }

        uint128_t(uint128_t val){
            UPPER = val.upper();
            LOWER = val.lower();
        }

        uint64_t upper(){
            return UPPER;
        }

        uint64_t lower(){
            return LOWER;
        }
};
```

if the operators are in the class, they work fine. however, i can do `uint128_t ^ uint32_t` but not `uint32_t ^ uint128_t`. on the other hand, moving everything outside is giving me `error: 'uint128_t operator=(uint128_t, T)' must be a nonstatic member function`. also, operator= will not work for a constant input apparently, since the values will be ULLL, which doesnt exist, unless someone know of a way to do so.

what should i do?

Comment: This compiles?  It shouldn't.  Your copy constructor is illegal.  It takes it's parameter by value, but that's impossible, because you can't pass parameters by value unless you already have a copy constructor.  It should accept it's parameter by const reference.  In fact, you shouldn't even define it, since the default copy constructor will work fine in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not a mix of both?
Put operator= inside, and the rest outside.

For the ones that take uint128_t as left-hand-side argument it doesn't matter, if it's a right-hand-side argument then it has to be a global function. So for that reason you can put both functions side-by-side if they're global. You might even get away with a clever macro to have one implementation for both, if only for the commutative ones.

Comment: i guess i will put the rhs functions outside. could you possible answer another question about this? ill create a new thread for it

Answer (score 0):

In general it's better to put them outside so for a `class X` with an implicit constructor from type `Y`, a single function `operator+(X&, const X&)` allows you to add X's and Y's ala `x + y` and `y + x`.  If you can see a way to - and wish to - make `x + y` and/or `y + x` faster than `x + x` then you may want separate functions anyway.  One thing to keep in mind: it's often good to have an `operator+=` member function then implement `+` in terms of returning a temporary copy of the lhs (left-hand-side value) after doing a `+=` of the rhs....